# How to escape all quotes in $* to pass it to PowerShell from CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd, doskey

I experience some problem with executing `PowerShell` command from `CMD`.

I have a function `MyFunction` in PowerShell which takes two parameters: `Id` and `Text`.
Example:

```bsh
MyFunction 12345 "Name = Karl"
```

I need to call this function from `CMD`:

```sh
powershell -Command . { MyFunction $* }
```

where `$*`: `12345 "Name = Karl"`

But I get error:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Karl'
```

The cause of it is quotes are being removed from passing parameters

[image]

I figured out I need to escape all quotes in passing parameters but I really don't know how to do it within `$*`. I'm not expert in `CMD`, could you please help me to solve the issue?

**Update (12/25/2019)**

I forgot to mention I'm creating an alias via `doskey` and I don't know how to escaping quotes within `$*`

```sh
MyFunction=powershell -Command . { MyFunction $* }
```

Comment: Have you tried backslash escaping the quotes?

Comment: You should provide your parameter values as separated values. For better readability I would suggest to provide your parameters and values by named parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`doskey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey) macros do *not* support pre-processing of arguments passed (`$*`), which is what is required in your case.

**Preprocessing of the arguments is required**, because you're using the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s **`-Command` parameter** - of necessity, since you're calling a *function* - where **the arguments undergo an *additional* round of parsing after PowerShell strips them of enclosing `"..."`**: the resulting values are concatenated and then interpreted as a piece of PowerShell code - and by that time what was originally `"Name = Karl"` is seen as *3* individual arguments, `Name`, `=`, and `Karl`.
To solve that problem, **you'd have to use *embedded* quoting**, by passing `"Name=Karl"` as `"\"Name = Karl\""` (sic) instead.

However, **you wouldn't have that problem if you used `-File` instead of `-Command`**, but that only works when you call a *script file* (`*.ps1`).

Here's a **workaround**:

- **Create an auxiliary `*.ps1` file** named, say, `MyFunction.ps1`, with the following content:

```bsh
MyFunction $args
```

<sup>Be sure that *function* `MyFunction` is actually defined in your PowerShell sessions. By virtue of being a *function*, it takes precedence over a script with the same base name.</sup>

- Then redefine your `doskey` macro as follows (adjust the path as needed; if you placed `MyFunction.ps1` in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`, you don't need to specify a path):

```
doskey MyFunction=powershell -File C:\path\to\MyFunction.ps1 $*
```

Comment: @lit: I've added a link to the help topic to the answer. `doskey` isn't really worth using in PowerShell - use the latter's aliases and functions. The `$`-based syntax was presumably only chosen to allow you to type macro definitions without fear of `cmd` prematurely expanding references such as `%*`.